# Matlab: artifacts when creating 3D figure from contour lines

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot 3 levels of amplitude and map it to another distance to get a cone-like 3D figure. Here is a original  picture with levels of 90%, 80% and 70% of maximum:
[image]

Here is the data for contour lines: https://pastebin.com/NUaJJbpt .

I chose to use shapeAlpha() to plot a 3D polygon:

```
clear;
c11 = load('cntr1.txt', '-ascii');
c21 = load('cntr2.txt', '-ascii');
c31 = load('cntr3.txt', '-ascii');
c11(:, 1:2) = c11(:, 1:2)-100.;
c21(:, 1:2) = c21(:, 1:2)-100.;
c31(:, 1:2) = c31(:, 1:2)-100.;
c12(:, 1:2) = c11(:, 1:2).*804./540.;
c22(:, 1:2) = c21(:, 1:2).*804./540.;
c32(:, 1:2) = c31(:, 1:2).*804./540.;
c11(:, 3) = 540.;
c21(:, 3) = 540.;
c31(:, 3) = 540.;
c11 = [c11; c21];
c21 = [c21; c31];
c12(:, 3) = 804.;
c22(:, 3) = 804.;
c32(:, 3) = 804.;
c12 = [c12; c22];
c22 = [c22; c32];
P1 = [c11(:,1), c11(:,2), c11(:,3); c12(:,1), c12(:,2), c12(:,3)];
P2 = [c21(:,1), c21(:,2), c21(:,3); c22(:,1), c22(:,2), c22(:,3)];
P3 = [c31(:,1), c31(:,2), c31(:,3); c32(:,1), c32(:,2), c32(:,3)];
P1 = unique(P1, 'rows');
P2 = unique(P2, 'rows');
P3 = unique(P3, 'rows');
figure;
hold on;
axis equal;
shp1 = alphaShape(P1(:,1), P1(:,2), P1(:,3), Inf);
shp2 = alphaShape(P2(:,1), P2(:,2), P2(:,3), Inf);
shp3 = alphaShape(P3(:,1), P3(:,2), P3(:,3), Inf);
h3 = shp3.plot;
h2 = shp2.plot;
h1 = shp1.plot;
set(h1,'edgecolor', 'none', 'facealpha', 0.2, 'facecolor', 'green');
set(h2,'edgecolor', 'none', 'facealpha', 0.2, 'facecolor', 'blue');
set(h3,'edgecolor', 'none', 'facealpha', 0.4, 'facecolor', 'red');
view(3);
hold off;
```

This is what I get:

[image]

As I understand, the color interference is happening because every figure is solid, without holes, and I need the inner circle to be solid, and two outer levels to be the "rings". I've tried various values of `HoleThreshold` and `RegionThreshold` but then I get wrong or incomplete rendering.

My question: how to create a plot of three amplitude levels with various colors and transparency so that they don't interfere with each other?

Comment: Sure thing. Since you actually have the contour lines, you should be able to create the 'rings'/'hollow cylinders'. If you still want to achieve this, could you add some more info on what your `cxx` represent?

Comment: @rinkert it's a beam of gamma particles measured at some distance, `cxx` are isolines for 90, 80 and 70% of max value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy fix to avoid the ugly color rendering for the top and bottom is to give the z values of `P1`, `P2` and `P3` a slight offset from each other:

```
offset = 0.1;
P2(:,3) = P2(:,3) + offset;
P3(:,3) = P3(:,3) + offset*2;
```

However, the volumes still are solids this way, and thus the transparent volumes do still overlap.

Comment: many thanks! I've increased Z values for c21, c31 and reduced for c22, c32, and now I have a clean plot without artifacts.

Comment: To add to this good answer: this is called Z-fighting in computer graphics literature, and its generally solved like this.